# How can I share ansible-galaxy collection modules for all users?

Tags: ansible

I am installing ansible on another environment and I get this error when I run my playbook
`ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'mount'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.`

I fixed this partialy by installing ansible.posix under root

`ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.posix`

but when I run this playbook under some user I get this error again.
Looks that modules are not shared.

Maybe is related that also my core ansible installation not finished 100% OK. I installed it via pip.
I created another Q here

https://superuser.com/questions/1778858/building-wheel-for-ansible-setup-py-error-unable-to-install-ansible

Update:
Ansible Core installation failed with this:

```
#python3 -m pip install --upgrade --user ansible
Collecting ansible
  Using cached ansible-4.10.0.tar.gz (36.8 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: ansible-core~=2.11.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ansible) (2.11.12)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ansible-core~=2.11.7->ansible) (3.0.3)
...
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from packaging->ansible-core~=2.11.7->ansible) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography->ansible-core~=2.11.7->ansible) (2.21)
Building wheels for collected packages: ansible
  Building wheel for ansible (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j1e8ee0o/ansible_739f732c70454ae68e5938304ea21a71/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j1e8ee0o/ansible_739f732c70454ae68e5938304ea21a71/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-188w1992
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-j1e8ee0o/ansible_739f732c70454ae68e5938304ea21a71/
  Complete output (4095 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'ansible_collections/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  creating build/lib/ansible_collections
  copying ansible_collections/ansible_release.py -> build/lib/ansible_collections
...
... final error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3cu3mwhw/ansible_acd23d78d456418e9c4c2c02e0e9312a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3cu3mwhw/ansible_acd23d78d456418e9c4c2c02e0e9312a/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-dysgpttw/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /root/.local/include/python3.6m/ansible Check the logs for full command output.
```

when I try install wheel, i get this error

```
#/root/.local/bin/pip install wheel
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.37.1)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

UPDATE:

Workaround was to install it manually:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.posix
ansible-galaxy collection install community.general
```

and then copy and share to all

```
cp -r /root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections /usr/share/ansible/collections/
chmod -R a+rX /usr/share/ansible/collections/
```

add collections PATH to ansible.cfg

`collections_paths = /usr/share/ansible/collections/`

Answer (score 1):

By default, ansible looks for collections in `~/.ansible/collections` which can be changed using the `COLLECTION_PATHS` option (check the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#collections-paths)).

I'm not sure if `ansible-galaxy` will respect this setting, but when installing a role or collection, you can force the path using the `-p` argument. Run `ansible-galaxy collection install --help` to view all available options.

If I remember correctly, `ansible.posix` should be part of the default installation, so if it is missing, I would assume something went wrong when you installed `ansible`.

I usually install ansible in a `venv` to isolate it from other python programs I have installed. You could even share that venv between users and you could also share a directory that contains your collections.
But for the sake of simplicity, I would recommend to always use the same user to run your playbooks.

Comment: I fixed this with manually collection install, and then I share it via collections_paths,
I am just curios why my initially core ansible installation failed to install all.
I shared my results above.

Comment: Please keep it to one question per post and especially don't add or completely change the question in an edit. Otherwise you will confuse people who find this post later.